# Cannot get existing subscriber on List using MailChimp API V3.0 and PHP

Tags: php, json, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Am trying to build a download library where users subscribe through MailChimp so they can download file as member, I would like to confirm the user email before generating download link else add the new email entered by the user to mailing list, I tried this code to get an existing email but nothing happens, please show me where I am wrong.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        // MailChimp API credentials
        $apiKey = '*******************';
        $listID = '**********';

        // MailChimp API URL
        $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

        // member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => 'subscribed'
        ]);

        // send a HTTP POST request with curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);


        // store the status message based on response code
        if ($httpCode == 200) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #34A853">You have subscribed.</p>';         
        } else {
            switch ($httpCode) {
                case 214:
                    $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                    break;
                default:
                    $msg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                    break;
            }
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">'.$msg.'</p>';
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
    }
}
// redirect to homepage
header('location:download.php');
```

Case 214 didn't fire any message... Tried don't know what's wrong..

Comment: There's a possibility that your code encountered an error before it reached this line: `if ($httpCode == 200)`, hence you didn't get any message.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working see full source code

```
<?php
session_start();
$statusMsg = !empty($_SESSION['msg'])?$_SESSION['msg']:'';
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
?>

    <h2>Subscribe Our Newsletter</h2>
    <?php echo $statusMsg; echo @$msg; ?>
    <form method="post" action="action.php">

        <p><label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE"/></p>
    </form>
```

action.php code

```
        // member information
$arr = array('email_address' => $email, 'status' => '');
$json = json_encode($arr);

        // send a HTTP POST request with curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);


        // store the status message based on response code
        if ($json->{'status'} == 400) {
                $_SESSION['msg'] = ' <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <div class="formstatus error">You have not subscribe to our mail List!</div>';  

        } elseif($json->{'status'} == 'subscribed') {
            if ($num) {
               $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="formstatus" style="color: #EA4335"><a href="'.$url.'">Download Now</a></div>';
            }
            else
            {
               $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="formstatus error">This file does not exist!</div>';     
            }

        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
    }
}
// redirect to homepage
header('location:download.php?file='.$file_id.' ');
```

See [Demo](http://demo.codexpresslabs.info/download.php?file=9)